# anyone can recommend a good code coverage tool for visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-coverage

1. C++ Code
2. integrate with Visual Studio (2017+)
3. has the option to generate a report (with results and etc)
4. doesnt need anything beside a visual studio solution with my source files compiled and run by an .exe
5. runs on my own console exe (without unit tests etc)

anyone has and recommended program for that?

we recently worked with DevPartner but that product has gone to "end of life"

thanks!